# Xamarin + SignalR (sending is possible, but not receiving messages)

Tags: c#, xamarin, dependency-injection, signalr, signalr.client

I can send messages
but my OnReceiveMessage event does not trigger?

Server side

```
public void Send(string name, string message, string roomname)
{
    //All connected clients in a specified group
    Clients.Group(roomname).OnMessageReceived(name, message);
}
```

Xamarin, my chatservice

```
public event EventHandler<ChatMessage> OnMessageReceived;

public async Task Connect()
{
    await _connection.Start();
    _proxy.On("OnMessageReceived", (string name, string message) => OnMessageReceived(this, new ChatMessage
    {
        Name = name,
        Message = message
    }));
 }
```

Xamarin Code behind from a chatpage

```
public ChatViewModel(List<MessageViewModel> messages)
{
    Messages = new ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel>(messages);
    _chatServices = DependencyService.Get<IChatServices>();
    _Channel = "PrivateRoom";
    _chatServices.Connect();
    _chatServices.JoinRoom(_Channel);
    _chatServices.OnMessageReceived += _chatServices_OnMessageReceived;
}
private void _chatServices_OnMessageReceived(object sender, ChatMessage e)
{
    // NO TRIGGER
}
```

Comment: Is OnMessageReceived invoked on the client if the server pushes it to all clients (instead of just the room)?

Comment: @AndrewTavera, had to enable cors it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to enable CORS on my web application.

1) Install the package 'Microsoft.Owin.Cors'.

2) Map signalR and allow it to use CORS.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {         
        app.Map("/signalR", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { };
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }
```